# Using proxy on Python SMTP

Tags: python, email, proxy, smtp

I want to try hiding my main IP and send email using Hotmail SMTP via Python SMTP Lib. I'm using the following code to send email but its sent from my IP (Originally it sends from Hotmail SMTP but it still shows my IP in the header if can see).

```
import smtplib
SMTP = "smtp.live.com"
s = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP,587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls() 
s.ehlo()
s.login("username@hotmail.com", "Password")
s.sendmail("username@hotmail.com", "recipient@hotmail.com","Hello World")
```

Let me know if there's any thing possible from which I can hide my IP and use the proxy IP to send the email. Furthermore, I think playing with socket/socks library might do the trick but still unsure.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you could easily do that, the world would have even a bigger spam problem than it has now. SMTP relays normally forward the client IP (even open relays).
I don't see how doing anything on the client would help you.

Comment: Actually my clients server accept only certain IPs and we only want to use those to send. There are many emails and no one other than those IP emails should go in. Basically it's within a networking and if someone tries to send outside it, it should be flagged or something.

Comment: Ok, the goal is clear. I'm not sure how it maps to your original question though which was about hiding your own IP and not server-side validation,

Comment: Basically we don't want the client to send emails from their own IP and instead use our IP for clients security purposes and account safety

Comment: I think your option is to create an email relay in your infrastructure, do whatever validation you need to do, and then send the SMTP request to the original destination.
You would also need to change MX records for the target server to point to you (assuming you own the domain of the eventual target).